# Do i need to use synthesize

Tags: objective-c, properties

I'm fairly new to objective-c, and I want to write a model class in iOS 7 using ARC,      but I'm not sure whether I need the `synthesize` in the .m file. Could any one give me some advice on this?

```
//user.h
@interface User : NSObject
@property(nonatomic, assign) NSInteger age;
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *firstname;
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *lastname;
@end  

//user.m
@implementation User
@synthesize age, firstname, lastname;
@end
```

Now comes my question:

Is the user.m file's `synthesize` necessary or not if in another class (e.g. `ViewContoller` class), I want to read & set the User class's `age` property, or `firstname`/`lastname` properties?

Comment: No. With modern Objective-C there is no need to call `@synthesize` if all you need is the default property behavior.

Answer (score 4):

**Not needed** . Modern objective C compiler will auto synthesize the properties for you. Its a compiler feature started with the LLVM 4.0 comes with Xcode 4.4. If you just want the default behaviour of property no need of manual `@synthesize`.

Comment: The only time you have to synthesize is when you write custom accessor methods but you still want the ivar to be synthesized (a getter in the case of `readonly`, both a getter and setter in the case of `readwrite` properties). But since most of the time we're using the automatically synthesized accessor methods, you therefore don't need to manually synthesize the ivar.

Comment: This answer is actually wrong. Xcode has *nothing* at all to do with it. It's the Objective-C compiler that generates the property's instance variable and methods.

Comment: @Anil Once you remove any mention that Xcode will auto synthesize the properties I will undo my down vote. Remember, Xcode is just an IDE, not a compiler. You don't even need Xcode to get this feature.

Comment: @rmaddy Sure i will remove it. I know its technically wrong, its just a view of a common programmer :)